# Client Error: program with keypair (../program/target/deploy/helloworld-keypair.json) is not executable

Tags: solana-test-validator, client

I'm trying to run the client program after deploying https://github.com/dmakarov/simple-solana-program.git on localhost testnet.

Deployment works fine

```
cargo build-sbf --manifest-path=program/Cargo.toml
solana program deploy --use-quic -u localhost program/target/deploy/helloworld.so
```

But the client application failed with a weird error `program with keypair (../program/target/deploy/helloworld-keypair.json) is not executable`

Command to run the client

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run -- -k ../program/target/deploy/helloworld-keypair.json -u localhost

warning: use of deprecated method `solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient::get_recent_blockhash`: Please use `get_latest_blockhash` instead
  --> src/client.rs:39:42
   |
39 |     let (_, fee_calculator) = connection.get_recent_blockhash()?;
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(deprecated)]` on by default

warning: `client` (lib) generated 1 warning
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.49s
     Running `target/debug/client -k ../program/target/deploy/helloworld-keypair.json -u localhost`
Connected to remote solana node running version (1.18.0).
(1418720) lamports are required for this transaction.
(500000001217422600) lamports are owned by player.
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:66:70:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidConfig("program with keypair (../program/target/deploy/helloworld-keypair.json) is not executable")
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:645:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/result.rs:1649:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/result.rs:1073:23
   4: client::main
             at ./src/main.rs:66:19
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```